# eye blink detection for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, opencv, ios5, face-detection, blink

Now that face detection is possible with ios 5, i am just wondering is it also possible to detect blinking eyes? I read the frameworks, but i just got methods for getting the position of eyes. Also, i have heard of OpenCV framework for iphone which has face detection. Will i get my blinking work done by OpenCV framework??

Can anyone help me for some stuff on openCV or on face/blink detection?? All i require is blink detection on iphone/ipad.

Any suggestions/replies welcomed... Thanx.

EDITED : 
As iOS 5 is under NDA, please suggest me if this detection is possible via OpenCV framework??

Comment: Since iOS 5 is still under NDA your are not allowed to talk about it here. You should ask your question on the special iOS 5 SDk forum on https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the eyes with openCV.

Take a look here

http://opencv-code.com/OpenCV_Eye_Detection

From that, you can adapt your algorithm to track changes in the eye area, and find a way to formulate the blink of the eye based on these changes.

Comment: Okay thanks, but can you help with some articles or tutorials for developing algorithm for blinking eyes?

Comment: Take a look at this  http://opencv-code.com/Real_Time_Eye_Tracking_and_Blink_Detection

Comment: The page is down... that is why in Stack Overflow policy complete answers are desirable over just links to external pages.

Answer (score 4):

Now in iOS 7, CoreImage supports eye blink. Here is the API diff from beta 2:

> Here is the API diff in iOS 7 Beta 2:
>
> CoreImage
>
> CIDetector.h
>
> Added CIDetectorEyeBlink
>
> Added CIDetectorSmile

Comment: In my iOS app, user will access their data with verifying their face with camera roll. After installing the app, new user will be registered in app.  How I can do with ARKit and MLKit in swift ? Right now , I can create .mlmodel with user photos for specific person and add it to my project. But how I can do it for later registered user ? Should process the .mlmodel from macOS machine and send it to app with a API ?  Is their any way to simple verify face of user to recognize their name tag identity ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hey in iOS 5 there is a class named CIDetector. There you can detect not only faces but its feature like left eye, mouth etc. Check the developer documentation for more details.

Comment: yea i checked this at the time of asking my question. However, it didnt have anything related to Eye-Blink detection. Did u find anything related to blinks?

Comment: I dint find for the blinks but I was able to detect the face, eyes and mouth. He will give u CGPoint and a boolean to tell whether it is present or not and it will not detect on many photos some preconditions are there I think. I just checked. No eye blinks as of now and no samples by apple. They may improve in next release.